# Uso do IEnumerable

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq

Vi um exemplo em outro Post sobre o uso do `IEnumerable`

```
var ent = new EntFuncionarios(); 
IEnumerable<Funcionario> funcionario = ent.Funcionarios;
IEnumerable<Funcionario> temp = funcionario.Where(x => x.FuncID == 2).ToList<Funcionario>();
```

Minha é dúvida é em relação a linha `var ent = new EntFuncionarios()`, do que se trata, é um método da classe Funcionarios?

Comment: Convém dizer que o `ToList<Funcionario>()` deveria ser removido (ou a variável deveria ser tipada como `List<Funcionario>` ou "`var`"). O método `Where` [já tem como retorno `IEnumerable<TSource>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb549418(v=vs.100).aspx) (no caso, IEnumerable<Funcionario>). O que essa linha faz, é converter um `IEnumerable<Funcionario>` para `ToList<Funcionario>` e depois, converter de novo para `IEnumerable<Funcionario>`.

Comment: @AndreFigueiredo Se remover o `ToList`, o codigo fica funcionalmente diferente. A primeira conversao de `IEnumerable` para `List` produz efeitos funcionais (ex, concretiza uma late-bound query), enquanto que a segunda conversao e' uma reference conversion, ou upcast. Se o `ToList` deve ser removido ou nao, ninguem pode responder, porque pode ou nao ser necessario para o caso de uso em concreto, do qual nao sabemos nada.

Comment: Sim. Mas o meu ponto é que, o `ToList` irá executar a query e depois atribuir isso ao mesmo tipo `IEnumerable` de novo ao invés de simplesmente deixá-lo como `ToList`. Se o resultado esperado é efetuar a query mesmo, por que tipar seu resultado como `IEnumerable`?

Comment: Sim, concordo, se o objectivo e' mesmo chamar o `ToList`, entao a variavel local deve ser do tipo `List<T>`, nao ha razoes para o contrario

Comment: Pelo que entendi poderia ser assim: var temp = funcionario.Where(x => x.FuncID == 2).ToList<Funcionario>();?

Comment: @JotaJotaJota também poderia. Neste caso ficaria mais adequado ao que o Andre e o dcastro estão falando. Neste caso `temp` seria do tipo `List<Funcionario>` que é o tipo de retorno do método `ToList`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Não. Ele é o construtor da classe `EntFuncionarios()`. E ela é a entidade que representa os funcionários. Ela tem ligação com a classe `Funcionario`, óbvio. Ela é necessária para uso com o padrão do [Entity Framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity_Framework).

Ela é gerada através do arquivo `.edmx` existente na solução. Pelo menos quando se usa os modelos *Model Fisrt* ou *Database First*.

## IEnumerable

O `IEnumerable` aí está sendo usado por outro motivo. Ele representa um tipo concreto que possui uma capacidade de pegar item por item de uma coleção. Neste caso (não dá para falar muito sem conhecer todos os detalhes) ele permite varrer todos os funcionários contidos na `EntFuncionarios`. Isto é feito na última linha através de uma técnica de consulta chamada [LINQ](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_Integrated_Query).

Comment: Agradeço a resposta, seria o que esta mapeado no .edmx?

Comment: Eu não uso o EF por isto não posso te fazer com precisão, mas é comum esta classe ser criada à partir do modelo que está definido neste arquivo sim. Dependendo da forma como está usando o EF. Acredito que neste caso seja *Model Fisrt*. Me corrijam se estiver errado. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj650889.aspx

Comment: Obrigado! Ajudou muito!

Comment: *Database First* também.

Comment: @AndreFigueiredo sim, claro. Certamente não é *Code First* :) Neste caso escreve-se a classe na mão para definir o modelo e criar o *database*.

Comment: Vou fazer isto. É porque tentei votar e estava liberado.

Answer (score 5):

Quer dizer que a variável `ent` tem uma instância de dados do tipo `EntFuncionarios`, já definida na base de dados.

Por outras palavras, é como se fosse uma nova linha de dados na tabela `EntFuncionarios`, onde todos os valores estão a `null`, prontos a serem instanciados.

Comment: Obrigado pela atenção dispensada.